# Java regex matches method returning false

Tags: java, regex, date, return-value

I'm trying to make a regex to detect if there's a date in a string, no matter if it's:

- `DD/MM/YYYY`
- `DD/MM/YY`
- `MM/DD/YYYY`
- `MM/DD/YY`
- `YYYY/MM/DD`
- `YY/MM/DD`

I tried to test it in a class using `Pattern.matches()` but it returns `false` even though I have some dates in my string and [regex101](https://regex101.com/) seems to say that my regex is correct.

Here's the code with which I tested:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String line = "31/07/12;401000;02/04/2013;400;";
        System.out.println(Pattern.compile("\\d{2,4}/\\d{2}/\\d{2,4}").matcher(line).matches());
    }
}
```

I was wondering if maybe it was an option problem but I can't find anything that'd go in that direction. What can I do to make it return `true`?

Comment: Shouldn't you be matching the date strings one by one? You're putting all the dates into one string and separating them by semicolon, that's not going to match your regex.

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this. Check and see if the matcher can find any match and then print out the group that matches.

```
String line = "31/07/12;401000;02/04/2013;400;";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d{2,4}/\\d{2}/\\d{2,4}").matcher(line);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

prints

```
31/07/12
02/04/2013
```

Note that your regex may also match incorrectly specified dates.  For example both day and month can't both be four digits at the same time.  You would be better off having multiple patterns.

Comment: Your solution works fine, thank you. I know that my regex isn't the best but I sadly can't know beforehand what date format the file read would have on the project I'm working on and I'm not the best with regex. That's why this regex is just the first step of my method to remove some date format and then continue removing out other potential formats depending on the result.